# how to use another thread to stop NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access the android network by starting a TCP server. But when I create a new thread, either by 
    `Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.start();`

or `FutureTask` I still get the `networkonmainthreadexception`...

Comment: you are doing network related operation on the ui thread, use asynctask or create anew thread. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: I see you are new here. Please search your question first as most of the time there will be answers already and this is one of them. Try to create a background thread as @Raghunandan pointed out and ask a more specific question with things you've tried and relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the actual network IO on the run() function of the runnable in the thread.  You don't just create a thread and then do the IO.

Comment: interesting point. i have some networking code in the construction of the runnable class, i will move it into the run method. I think this is probably the reason!

Answer (score 2):

Use AsyncTask to perform network related ops

For Example :

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";
      for (String url : urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
          InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
          String s = "";
          while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
    }
  }
```

Or you can do this, Although it is not recommended

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
                new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

adding this code will not give you network on main thread exception anymore.

Comment: i did use the asynctask and that worked fine. but i need a few threads running and i dont think asynctask is the best solution to that... but thank you for the response